# XPath - selecting descendants - difference between using // and */

Tags: html, xml, xpath

Can someone help me understand the difference between the two following XPath queries:

A: `//table[@id="xyz"]//tr[//a[contains(text(), "Alice")]]`

B: `//table[@id="xyz"]//tr[*/a[contains(text(), "Alice")]]`

(A) appears to select all the `tr`'s in the table regardless of whether it has an `a` descendent with the text "Alice".

(B) meanwhile does what I expect in only selecting the `tr`s with `a` descendents containing the text "Alice".

As an aside question, is there a more elegant way of writing the above?

Comment: (B) will select `tr` elements that have a _grandchild_ `a` element whose _first text node child_ contains "Alice".  It'll find `<tr><td><a href="#">Alice</a></td></tr>` but it won't find `<tr><td><span><a>Alice</a></span></td></tr>` (the `a` is not a grandchild) and it won't find `<tr><td><a><span>Alice</span></a></td></tr>` (the "Alice" text node is not a direct child of the `a`) nor `<tr><td><a>I <i>love</i> Alice</a></td></tr>` (Alice is in the _second_ text node).  You probably want to use `.//` instead of `*/` and `.` instead of `text()` - `tr[.//a[contains(., 'Alice')]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use `//table[@id="xyz"]//tr[.//a[contains(text(), "Alice")]]` or `//table[@id="xyz"]//tr[descendant::a[contains(text(), "Alice")]]` to make sure that in the first expression the path in square brackets is relative to the `tr`. With your current `//tr[//a]` inside the predicate the selection `//a` starts from the document node, the root node, and is not relative to the `tr`.

Comment: But, to be clear, the `//tr` I'm using after the `//table` that's still only looking for descendents of `table`, right?

Comment: Effectively, yes, see http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev which explains "// is short for /descendant-or-self::node()/. For example, //para is short for /descendant-or-self::node()/child::para and so will select any para element in the document (even a para element that is a document element will be selected by //para since the document element node is a child of the root node); div//para is short for div/descendant-or-self::node()/child::para and so will select all para descendants of div children."

Answer (score 0):

`//a` selects all a elements anywhere in the document.

`*/a` selects all a elements that are grandchildren of the context node.

`.//a` selects all a elements that are descendants of the context node at any depth

`./a` (or just a) selects all a elements that are children of the context node.

It's vital to understand the notion of context. In a predicate such as tr[XXXX] the context node for evaluating XXXX is the tr element that you are testing.